# asp.net doesnt display the string as I wanted in html

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I need to display first 24 characters in a string in two lines. I am trying to show a diagram to explain how I want the string as below.

```
--------------
|month has th|
|irthy days  |
```

as you can see, there are spaces as well.

my problem is When I try to display the string, it displays as below.

```
--------------
|month has   |
|thirty days |
```

How can I display as in First Diagram?

here is the way I am trying to do it

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
     if(temp_name[j].ToString() != Environment.NewLine)
         name += temp_name[j];

     name += Environment.NewLine;

for (int j = 13; j <= 24; j++)
     if (temp_name[j].ToString() != Environment.NewLine)
         name += temp_name[j];
```

I am writing the first 12 chars and put a new line, then next twelve chars

here is the picture why I need this feature.

[image]
My main screen cannot display the items properly as you can see. I put that bold short horizontal line to display the difference

here is the aspx markup,

```
s += "<span class='th radius'><div id='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString() + "' class='div_product_id two mobile-one columns' style='cursor:pointer;'>" +
                                         "<img src='images/galvaniz_boru.jpg'>" +
                                         "<div class='panel'><span style='font-size:11px'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString() + "<br />" + name + "</span>" +
                                         "<p class='subheader'>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString() + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString() + "</p></div></div></span>";
```

Comment: Show us the code that you are using.

Comment: exactly how/where are you outputting this? an answer for a fixed-width character-based output (e.g. command line/terminal) is pointless if you're doing this in a gui with variable width fonts.

Comment: added the c# code above

Comment: Where are outputting the data to?  Is it going into a text box, or what?

Comment: Please show your aspx markup.

Comment: added the markup. and I think I posted everything I have :) Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not outputting 12 characters;

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 12; j++)
    if(temp_name[j].ToString() != Environment.NewLine)
     name += temp_name[j];

 name += Environment.NewLine;
```

This causes name to get the first *13* characters (since you are consuming the 12th indexed element as well).

```
for (int j = 13; j <= 24; j++)
     if (temp_name[j].ToString() != Environment.NewLine)
         name += temp_name[j];
```

This does consume 12 characters, but it is starting off at the wrong index; the loop should be something like this:

```
for(int j = 12; j < 24; j++)
    //etc
```

You could have also just used something like:

```
name += temp_name.Substring(0, 12); // do some checking by the way on length of temp_name!
name += "<br />";
name += temp_name.Substring(12, 12); //again, do some checking
```

Also, change your `Environment.NewLine` to `"<br />"` since this will be displayed using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not recognize `Environment.NewLine`. You need to use the line break tag `<br />` instead.

Line 5 becomes:

```
name += "<br />";
```

Comment: How are you displaying the text in the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
<pre id="MyPre" runat="server">
</pre>

protected void ButtonServer_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String MyString = "month has thirty days";

    MyString = MyString.Insert(12, "\n");

    MyPre.InnerText = MyString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim str As String = "bu bir dübel, hem de gömlekli"
Dim str1 As String = Mid(str, 0, 12) ' bu bir dübel,
Dim str2 As String = Mid(str, 12, str.Length) ' hem de gömlekli
```